# gedit does not display "grid pattern"

Tags: gnome, gedit, 21.10

Possibly after the update from 21.04 to 21.10, the standard GNOME editor `gedit` started not displaying the background grid pattern.

- I tried to unset and set the **Display grid pattern** setting from `gedit`'s **Preferences** / **View** tab: Nothing changed. (All the other options -- except this one -- work as expected.)
- Using `dconf-editor`, I tried to change **org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor.background-pattern** attribute to 'default', 'none', and then back to 'grid': Nothing changed.
- Similarly, running the commands `gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor background-pattern 'none'` and
  `gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor background-pattern 'grid'` has no effect.
- I tried to remove `~/.cache` and `~/.config/gedit`: Nothing changed.
- I tried to login with Wayland, XOrg, etc. Also, I tried to change themes using `gnome-tweaks`: The problem stays the same.

On another (rarely used) user on the same system `gedit` works as expected: It displays or hides the grid depending on the selection **Display grid pattern** in **Peferences** / **View** tab. I am also able to change the "grid pattern" for the `root` user, after running `sudo -H gedit` for example.

This problem seems to be present only on my "main" user.

---

The Applications Theme I use in my current user is "Adwaita (default)" and it is not a dark theme.

The Color Scheme in `gedit` is "Yaru".

Comment: Which theme are you using in Ubuntu? Is it a dark theme? Which color scheme are you using in gedit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the "Yaru" (previously called "Yaru-light" in 21.04) *Color Scheme* was accidentally selected in `gedit`'s **Preferences** → **Font & Colors**. This scheme—even having a white background—does not allow the grid to be displayed. The other "light" schemes do not have this problem.